# How to write emails with PYAUTOGUI?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm actually learning to automate task with `PYAUTOGUI` with `python 3.x`.

Currently all work perfectly except when I try to write an `@`
I tried using `typewrite()` and `press()` same don'st write it.

With this code it write : `testgmx.fr`

```
a, b, c, d = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('email.png')
pyautogui.click(x=a, y=b, clicks=1, button='left')
pyautogui.typewrite('test@gmx.fr')
```

Comment: what happens when you use typewrite? what is the error?

Comment: It don't do error but it just ignore the @, if email is test@gmx.fr, it just write testgmx.fr. But I found a way to "fix" it, I use a module named pyperclip to copy the email adress to copyboard and CTRL+V it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to break your mail into two. From your example

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.typewrite('test')
pyautogui.hotkey('altright','2') # The @ hotkey in Windows PC
pyautogui.typewrite('gmx.fr')
```

Hope this helps